# Winsock UDP IO Completion Port: Unable to use WSASendTo

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winsock, iocp

I am trying to write a UDP server with a worker thread that keeps calling `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`. I can already receive data successfully with `WSARecvFrom` but sending data with `WSASendTo` causes the following error:

`10045: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced.`

I've been trying to fix this for hours now, reading documentation as well as rigorous trial and error. Switching the `WSASendTo` call to a blocking call fixes the issue, but then I have to deal with blocking IO. I also have almost the exact same code for TCP (`WSASend` instead of `WSASendTo`, etc.), and that works with IOCP without a hitch.

I've tried calling `connect`, not binding the socket, changing my `OVERLAPPED` struct, verified the `SOCKADDR*` parameter contains valid host/port combination, passing in a `lpNumberOfBytesSent` parameter. Nothing seems to make a difference.

**Basic flow of the program (code further below):**

- Create a socket with `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`
- Create an IO completion port and a worker thread
- Bind the socket to 127.0.0.1:2050
- Call `WSARecvFrom` (and connect with another client to set valid `PER_IO_DATA::SockAddrFrom`)
- `gets_s` input from the console and send it with `WSASendTo`

**My OVERLAPPED struct:**

```
typedef struct PER_IO_DATA
{
    OVERLAPPED Overlapped;
    SOCKET Socket;
    WSABUF wsaBuf;
    char Buffer[1024];
    DWORD Flags;
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddrFrom;
} PER_IO_DATA;
```

**Main function:**

```
//################################# Initialize ###############################
WSADATA wsaData;
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
    return 0;

//Create completion port
HANDLE hCompletionPort = CreateIoCompletionPort(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, 0, 0);
if (!hCompletionPort)
    return 0;

//Create and detach a worker thread
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, server_worker_thread, hCompletionPort, 0, NULL);
CloseHandle(hThread);

//Create UDP socket with overlapped IO
SOCKET Sock = WSASocketW(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP, NULL, 0, WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED);
if (Sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    WSAERROR();

//################################### Bind ###################################
//Bind socket to 127.0.0.1:2050
SOCKADDR_IN serverAddr = { 0 };
serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr.sin_port = htons(2050);
InetPtonA(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
if (bind(Sock, (SOCKADDR*)&serverAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) == -1)
    WSAERROR();

//Assign completion port
CreateIoCompletionPort((HANDLE)Sock, hCompletionPort, 0, 0);

//Create overlapped context
PER_IO_DATA* pPerIoData = malloc(sizeof(PER_IO_DATA));
ZeroMemory(pPerIoData, sizeof(PER_IO_DATA));

pPerIoData->Socket = Sock;
pPerIoData->Overlapped.hEvent = WSACreateEvent();
pPerIoData->wsaBuf.buf = pPerIoData->Buffer;
pPerIoData->wsaBuf.len = sizeof(pPerIoData->Buffer);

//################################## Receive #################################
int size = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);
if (WSARecvFrom(Sock, &pPerIoData->wsaBuf, 1, NULL,
    &pPerIoData->Flags, (SOCKADDR*)&pPerIoData->SockAddrFrom,
    &size, &pPerIoData->Overlapped, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    if (WSAGetLastError() != WSA_IO_PENDING)
        WSAERROR();
}

//################################### Send ###################################
while (TRUE)
{
    gets_s(pPerIoData->Buffer, sizeof(pPerIoData->Buffer));
    pPerIoData->wsaBuf.len = strlen(pPerIoData->Buffer);

    //Print outgoing data
    char addr[16];
    DEBUG("Sending %.*s (%d bytes) to %s:%d", pPerIoData->wsaBuf.len, pPerIoData->Buffer,
        pPerIoData->wsaBuf.len, InetNtopA(AF_INET, &pPerIoData->SockAddrFrom.sin_addr,
        addr, sizeof(addr)), ntohs(pPerIoData->SockAddrFrom.sin_port));

    //Send the data (this is where the error happens)
    if (WSASendTo(Sock, &pPerIoData->wsaBuf, 1, NULL,
        WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, (SOCKADDR*)&pPerIoData->SockAddrFrom, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN),
        &pPerIoData->Overlapped, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        if (WSAGetLastError() != WSA_IO_PENDING)
            WSAERROR(); //<-- Error 10045
    }
}

//################################## Clean up ################################
shutdown(Sock, SD_BOTH);
closesocket(Sock);

WSACleanup();
return 0;
```

**Example output:**

```
Received hello (5 bytes) from 127.0.0.1:50995
respond
Sending respond (7 bytes) to 127.0.0.1:50995
Error 10045: The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced.
```

The error message originates from my `WSAERROR` macro.

How can I call `WSASendTo` with `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` and have it be added to the IOCP message queue?

Comment: `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED== MSG_OOB` in call `WSASendTo` is error. here must be absolute another flags. almost always 0. exactly this and produce your error

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsasendto). `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` is not a valid flag to pass to `WSASendTo()`. Also, you must allocate a new `PER_IO_DATA` for each individual call to `WSARecvFrom()` and `WSASendTo()`. Do not reuse a single `PER_IO_DATA` like you are currently doing

Comment: also for what you create event - `Overlapped.hEvent = WSACreateEvent();` - this is not need, when you use iocp. you not need save `WSABUF wsaBuf`

Comment: @RbMm Thank you so much! I was agonizing over this for longer than I'm willing to admit. That fixed it right up.